# Where can I ask about deleting call logs from a phone?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have following question:

> How can I delete invalid selection errors in call logs on a Nokia C1?

Where can I ask it?

Comment: We have sites for Android, Apple (thus iOS) and Windows Phone but not a general phone/electronics site I'm afraid

Comment: @Jasmine As a user of the phone or are you writing some code that works with these calls logs?

Answer (score 5):

If you are a programmer and want to access the call logs through some sort of app for the phone, you can ask on [Stack Overflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com).

If not, your question is off-topic for sites in the Stack Exchange network. Super User does not accept questions about mobile devices ["except insofar as they interface with your computer"](https://superuser.com/faq), and the Nokia C1 does not run either iOS or Android, so Ask Different and Android SE can't help you.